# Convert Integer to Date issue

Tags: vba, excel

I as developing a program that imported cash from Yahoo Finance onto another Excel spreadsheet. Everything was working fine, then I wrote another function that uploaded the name of the business, and now suddenly the cash value is being displayed as a date and I am very confused.

```
  'WB1.Cells(i, 3) = CDate(WB2.Range("G3"))
    WB1.Cells(i, 4) = WB2.Range("G7")
  WB1.Cells(i, 4) = CLng(WB1.Cells(i, 4))
```

Comment: Set the `NumberFormat` of the cell you're writing to.

Answer (score 3):

Set the numberFromat of the cell

```
WB1.Cells(i, 4).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
```